# Getting Character Code from char

Tags: c++, char

I have an array of characters populated by `cin`, but im trying to find a way to check each character individually to make sure its only one of a set number of characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9,[space]).

The easiest way I thought this could be done is to check if the code of the character fell within a certain range. But not sure how to get it.

Alternatively if anyone knows any other ways of doing it, that would be great.

Comment: The functions in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype) might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `isalpha()`, `isdigit()` or `isalnum()`:

```
char ch = ...  //  The character

//  Original solution
if (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch)){

}

//  Better solution by fefe (see comments)
if (isalnum(ch)){

}
```

These are defined in `ctype.h`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/

Otherwise you can also use comparisons:

```
if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
    'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
    '0' <= ch && ch <= '9'
){

}
```

This latter approach using comparisons will generalize to arbitrary ranges.

Comment: ah, is that with ctype.h? sorry, tad new to c++

Comment: Was in the process of typing the first - therefore a point for nimble fingers!

Comment: @fefe: Wow, I didn't know that existed! Thanks! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Can also (preferably) use `#include <cctype>` and `isalpha` is in `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily access a specific character code by using the character you want in single quotes, for example, `'A'`. Therefore, if you wanted to check if a character is in a certain range:

```
char c = //some character
if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) {
    //do something
}
```

should work as you would expect. Additionally, if you are concerned about alpha-numerics specifically, there is a helper function called `isalnum`, defined in `<ctype.h>` that checks if a character is an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the number falls within the range you are looking for within an ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif. So >= 48 && < 123.

Comment: Though `xxx >= 'A' && xxx <= 'Z'` is easier and more reader/maintainer-friendly.

Comment: Agree, the other solutions are more appropriate.

Comment: Matches a huge variety of punctuation as well.  If you do it this way, check each range (32, 48-57, 65-90, 97-122) separately.